# Why my for in "list" doesn´t show the name and amount of every person that clicks the button?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with my js code because everything works perfect except the let in list. It doesn´t show the name of the person and his amount and i don´t know why. I´ve tried everything but nothing seems to work. Here´s my Code:

```js
const persons = []

let nameHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("name")
let amountHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("amount")
let totalHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("total")
let personsListHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("each-person")
let splitHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("split")

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", enterPerson)

function enterPerson() {

  let person = nameHTMLelemento.value;
  let amount = amountHTMLelemento.value;

  persons.push({
    name: person,
    amount: parseFloat(amount),
  });

  nameHTMLelemento.value = "";
  amountHTMLelemento.value = "";

  defineTotal();
}

function defineTotal() {

  personsListHTMLelemento = "";

  let list = "";
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    total += persons[i].amount
    list += `${persons[i].name}: ${persons[i].amount} <br>`;
  }

  let iva = 1.21

  totalHTMLelemento.innerHTML = total * iva;
  personsListHTMLelemento.innerHTML = list;
  splitHTMLelemento.innerHTML = (total * iva) / persons.length;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <h1>splitter bill</h1>
  <p>enter the name of the person and his amount (21% of iva included):</p>
  <label id="name-text">Nombre</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <br>
  <label id="monto-texto">amount</label>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="amount">
  <br>
  <button id="calculate">Ingresar</button>
  <p>Total: <span id="total"></span> </p>
  <div id="each-person">
  </div>
  <p> Cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="split"></span> </p>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Get rid of `personsListHTMLelemento = "";` That's redefining the variable that's supposed to hold the element where you want to display the list. I think you meant to empty it by assigning to `.innerHTML`, but that's not needed since you're going to overwrite it with the list.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar , that was what wasn´t working